# SSAS 3 fact tables, but only 2 relate to a certain dimension

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse

I have a cube with 3 fact tables and 20 + dimensions that relate easily to all 3 fact tables and everything works fine except for the fact that one of the dimensions (Warehouse) is only related to 2 of the 3 fact tables. My problem I guess is a display issue. When the user is viewing measures from all 3 fact tables then drags over the Warehouse dimension, it simply repeats the grand total of the measure in the 3rd fact table for every possible value of Warehouse. This certainly makes sense to me as there is no relationship set up and it's conceptually behaving almost like a cross-join. Nonetheless, it's confusing to users and I'd like to not have the grand total duplicated for each dimension member in Warehouse. I was thinking one solution was to create a dummy warehouse called "Not Applicable" and then relate every row in the 3rd fact table to that dimension member. I was hoping there's just a setting in SSAS where I could control this behavior so I didn't have to create any new warehouse values. Is there a standard way to handle non-related dimensions with multiple fact tables? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "IgnoreUnrelatedDimensions" property of the measure group not related to Warehouse: set it from the default value true to false. Then, measure values for this measure group will only be shown for the "All" members from the warehouse dimension, and the cells will be null (empty) for non-All members of this dimension.

This is a global setting per measure group, you cannot configure it individually per dimension and measure group. But for your purpose, this should be fine.